# How to perform a search with conditional where parameters using Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Usually whenever I write a search query for SQL, I do something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE (@username IS NULL OR u.username like '%' + @username + '%')
AND (@id IS NULL OR u.id = @id)
```

Basically this simulates a conditional WHERE clause. We only want to compare @searchParam to the column if @searchParam was provided.

Is there a way to replicate this using Sequelize?

**EDIT:** Here is my best attempt which fails:

```
models.user.findAll({
  where: {
    username: searchParams.username || models.sequelize.col('user.username'),
    id: searchParams.id || models.sequelize.col('user.id')
  }
})
```

**UPDATE:** I found a way to do it, but it feels like a workaround. I'm certain there has to be a more elegant way. This works, but is ugly:

```
models.user.findAll({
  where: [
    '(? IS NULL OR "user"."username" LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR "user"."id" = ?)',
    searchParams.username,
    `%${searchParams.username}%`,
    searchParams.id,
    searchParams.id
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can just prepare object with needed conditions. Simple and easy to understand

```
var whereStatement = {};
if(searchParams.id)
    whereStatement.id = searchParams.id;
if(searchParams.username)
    whereStatement.username = {$like: '%' + searchParams.username + '%'};
models.user.findAll({
  where: whereStatement
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this really does seem to be the best way. I was hoping to avoid creating a long string of if checks, but it seems unavoidable at this point.

Comment: When my `whereStatement` object remains empty i get an error. What to do then? Sequelize 5.18.

Answer (score 3):

that's pretty awesome. thank you. i use your ideas like that:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    ..
    let foo = await Foo.findAll(
    {
        offset: parseInt(req.query.offset | 0),
        limit: parseInt(req.query.limit | 10),
        where: getFooConditions(req),
    ...
}

function getFooConditions(req) {
  fooConditions = {};
  // Query param date
  if (req.query.date) {
    fooCondtions.start = {
      [Op.gte]: moment(parseInt(req.query.date)).utc().startOf('day'),
      [Op.lte]: moment(parseInt(req.query.date)).utc().endOf('day')
    }
  }
  // Query param name
  if (req.query.name) {
    fooCondtions.name = {
      [Op.like]: '%' + (req.query.name) + '%'
    }
  }
  // Query param id
  if (req.query.id) {
    fooCondtions.id = {
      [Op.equals]: '%' + (req.query.id) + '%'
    }
  }
  return fooConditions;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It'd be a little more complicated than you've outlined above. Sequelize has to have pretty explicit statements on ands and ors, and that means you have to use the `$and` and `$or` options to replicate what you're looking for. What you've done above is merely create the values in JavaScript and pass them to the database. Try the following:

```
models.user.findAll({
                where: {
                    $and: [{
                        $or: [{
                            username: {
                                $like: '%' + searchParams.username '%'
                            }
                        }, {
                            username: null
                        }]
                    }, {
                        $or: [{
                                id: searchParams.id
                        }, {
                           id: null
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            })
```

For more on this, and some good examples, see their [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/).

Comment: This is not quite the same thing. Your example will return everything that equals searchParams.id or equals null. I'm wanting to return everything if searchParams.id is null, or everything that equals searchParams.id. See the difference?

Comment: Basically, what I can't figure out is how to check if searchParams.id is null. You could easily do this in a raw query, but I don't see a way to do it with the Sequelize operators.