# Why my conditional WHERE inside the OR operator in the Sequelize query is converted to AND?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a query with Sequelize with a conditional WHERE like explained here ([How to perform a search with conditional where parameters using Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236837/how-to-perform-a-search-with-conditional-where-parameters-using-sequelize)).

The relevant part of my code is like this

```
    const Op = Sequelize.Op;
    var search = {};
     if (typeof req.query.search !== 'undefined'){
         search.nome = {[Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + '%'};
         search.username = {[Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + '%'};
    }
    model.User.findAll({
        where:{
         [Op.or]: [
           search
         ]
      })
```

It works, but the generated SQL adds an AND instead of an OR, like this:

```
    SELECT 'id_', 'nome', 'username', 'id' FROM 'User' AS 'User' WHERE (('User'.'nome' LIKE '%test%' AND 'User'.'username' LIKE '%test%'))
```

Am I doing something wrong that I fail to see?
I've already tried several combinations of this and none works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong in the constructed `search` filter. `[Op.or]` should be the spread of search not an array.

Try as below,

```
model.User.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      email: {
        [Op.like]: 'abcd',
      },
      username: {
        [Op.like]: 'cdf',
      },
    }
  },
  logging: console.log,
});
```

you will get the below,

```sql
    SELECT "id", "name", "username" FROM "users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("User"."email" LIKE 'abcd' OR "User"."username" LIKE 'cdf');
```

Comment: Yes I tried like this before and it works, but won't do for me because I want the `WHERE` clause dynamically constructed.

Comment: Spread search object inside the where key. I did mention it in the answer.

Comment: I see it now, thanks. I wasn't paying attention to the meaning of the brackets. Strangely, didn't have to spread the variable, just changed to `where: {[Op.or]: search }` and worked.

Comment: Yeah that will work since search is just an object constructed dynamically

Answer (score 0):

try to use spread

```
model.User.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      {...search}
    ]
  }
})
```

---

what about this?

```
const where = {}
     if (typeof req.query.search !== 'undefined'){
       where[Op.or] = {
         nome : {
          [Op.like] : `%${req.query.search}%`
         },
         username : {
          [Op.like] : `%${req.query.search}%`
        },
       }
    }

    model.User.findAll({
      where
    })
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I get the same result. If I take out the curly brackets I get `search is not iterable`

Comment: This won't work. Or operator does not accept an array.

Comment: @anoop http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators you can use array as you can see.

Comment: @kkangil yes you are right, it accepts. I was thinking combinations wasn't supported in arrays, but looks like it is. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4/docs/querying.md#combinations. Nice find.

Comment: @anoop yes that's what I said. I use it many times. but I wonder why the error, above code occurs.

Comment: @kkangil I think not using object spread plugins for transpiring

Comment: The edited code worked perfectly. As I commented on the other answer, the only problem with my code were the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I'm using:

```
return Models.job.findAndCountAll({
  raw: true,
  where: {
    isActive: 1,
    ...((args.statusOfJob > 0) && {
      status: args.statusOfJob
    })
  }
})
```

In this case, `statusOfJob` is a numerical value used in a select object, where 0 would show all items.

It's a bit cryptic, but it's also concise and reduces the need for extraneous conditional statements and assignments.