# How to search with conditional where parameters including [Op.or] and [Op.like using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42246755/13116501) I created some ifs and it works.

But also I need put in to object something like this:

```
    [Op.or]: [
    { '$createdBy.name$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterCreatedBy}%` } },
    { '$createdBy.surname$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterCreatedBy}%` } },
    ]
```

My find looks like this:

```
    Model.findAndCountAll({ 
    where: whereStatement,
            include: includeArray,
            attributes: {
              exclude: excludeArray,
            },
            limit,
            offset
          })
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
    if (filterCreatedBy) {
    whereStatement['[Op.or]'] = [
      { '$createdBy.name$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterCreatedBy}%` } },
      { '$createdBy.surname$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterCreatedBy}%` } },
    ]
    //Including model to where:
    includeArray.push({
      model: User, as: 'createdBy', attributes: ['id', 'name', 'surname'],
    });
    }`
```

But it's not working. Any ideas how i can do that?

EDIT:

This is working part of my code, also contains [Op]:

```
if (filterSubject) whereStatement.subject = { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterSubject}%` };
  if (filterName) whereStatement.name = { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterName}%` };
  if (filterRegion) {
    whereStatement['$region.name$'] = { [Op.iLike]: filterRegion };
  };
  if (filterDepartment) {
    whereStatement['$department.name$'] = { [Op.iLike]: `%${filterDepartment}%` };
  };
```

Comment: Can you show please `whereStatement` definition and its previous modifications?

Comment: You need to remove wrapping single quote.  `whereStatement[[Op.or]]`

Comment: When I removed single quote i get this error:
`TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string`

Comment: oops, sorry. you also need to remove extra brackets.  `whereStatement[Op.or]`

Comment: It's working! Thank you! I don't know why I didn't try it...